# Fastapi generate request based on another request

Tags: python, api, fastapi

is it possible to use fastapi to do conditional request?

I would like to have another dynamic dropdown selection "color option" within async def get_list( based on the "fruit" selection. Thank you!!!!!

Current Fastapi:
[image]

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from typing_extensions import Literal

app = FastAPI()

# TODO: Make color_option as dynamic request based on selected fruit
# TODO: Add is_ripe variable based on color_option selected


@app.post('/test/get_list',
          description="Determine Fruit Ripeness based on color")
async def get_list(
    request: Request,
    fruit: Literal['avocado', 'banana']):
    if fruit == "avocado":
        color_option = ["green", "brown"]  # FIXME: Make this as request
        color_selected = "green"
        if color_selected == "green":
            is_ripe = "ripe"
        else:
            is_ripe = "not ripe"

    elif fruit == "banana":
        color_option = ["green", "yellow"]  # FIXME: Make this as request
        color_selected = "yellow"
        if color_selected == "yellow":
            is_ripe = "ripe"
        else:
            is_ripe = "not ripe"

    return f"{fruit} color {color_selected} is {is_ripe}"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8081, debug=True)
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want to do - but I would do it as two separated function: one which gets only `fruit` and gives only `colors` for this `fruit`, and second which gets `fruit` and `color` and gives `ripe`, `not ripe`. Eventually this funcion should get second parametr `color` and if it gets `color=None` then it returns list of colors for `fruit`, and when it get `fruit` and `color` then it returns `ripe`, `not ripe`.

Comment: you could keep colors as dictionary `colors = {"avocado": ["green", "brown"], "banana": ["green", "yellow"]}`

Comment: Why is this backend code?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is converting the openapi schema into a dynamic front end and that is not the purpose of this tool.

- if you want to have a dynamic form for your fruit types:

I highly suggest you to build your routes following [the official user guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/), and use [jinja2 templates](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates) to build your dynamic frontend.

- If you don't want a dynamic frontend (but update your fruit according to their types):

you have to use pydantic models to create your different fruits, colors etc and enforce validation rules.

[here is a good example](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#literal-type) from the official pydantic doc:

```py
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


class Pie(BaseModel):
    flavor: Literal['apple', 'pumpkin']


Pie(flavor='apple')
Pie(flavor='pumpkin')
try:
    Pie(flavor='cherry')
except ValidationError as e:
    print(str(e))
    """
    1 validation error for Pie
    flavor
      unexpected value; permitted: 'apple', 'pumpkin'
    (type=value_error.const; given=cherry; permitted=('apple', 'pumpkin'))
    """
```

```py
from typing import Literal

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Pie(BaseModel):
    flavor: Literal['apple', 'pumpkin']


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/add_pie")
async def add_pie(my_pie: Pie):
    # do something with the pie
    return my_pie
```

with something like this it's pydantic that take care of the validation of the pie object (fruit in your case)